# Gradient of matrix in vertical direction in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can one use 
'gradient' function
for columns of a matrix? 
For example, I want to find gradient of matrix c for columns:
I expect below answer:

```
B(i,j) = c(i+1,j)-c(i-1,j) %for i is not equal t 1 or last row of matrix c
B(i,j) = c(i+1,j)-c(i,j) %for i is equal to 1
B(i,j) = c(i,j)-c(i-1,j) %for i is equal to last row of matrix c
```

I used below code but the answer is not what I wish.

```
c=[4,6,8,12;4,0,22,0;32,42,12,6;20,10,4,7]
B = gradient(c')'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [second output of `gradient`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html#outputarg_FY) will provide you with the gradient in the y direction

```
[~, ygrad] = gradient(c);
```

Comment: Your answer becomes completely correct if you put -ygrad instead of ygrad :)